# Can i configure a section in UITableView to be multi-select

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a requirement in my project, i want to configure a section to be multi-select in UITableView and rest of the sections as single-select. How can i achieve this ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Multi select in the sense 2 rows should be selected with 2 fingers ?

Comment: I am guessing @user1446500 means they would like to be able to select more than one row in say section 0 (I guess by displaying a checkmark), and be able to select only one row in section 1.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use following sample codes:

> http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/multiple-row-selection-in-iphone-table-view/
>
> https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/TableMultiSelect/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 0):

Upon My understanding from your question you need to delete multiple row on an action(say button taping)

You can use a checkmark per selected row by setting the accessoryType on the selected UITableViewCell instances to `UITableViewCelAccessoryCheckmark`.

To deselect the row, set it back to `UITableViewCellAccessoryNone`. Manage some NSArray for the selected row like in your table view delegate in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`" delegate method.
or 
you can enumerate which cells/rows were selected , simply iterate over the cells of the table looking for `UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark.`